# Why is Geddy not built on Connect?

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect, geddy

From this presentation http://techwraith.github.com/presentations/2012/nodepdx

The author states the following:

- "Connect also give you problems"
- "Connect buffers some responses"
- "Connect has no structure"
- "Express gives you all the problems Connect has"

With that said, most node frameworks are built on top of Connect.

So what makes Geddy significantly better than connect?
Does it scale any better?
Does Connect has issues?
Aside from the qualities of the framework, are the arguments above pertinent as of 2012?

Note: This is not a Express vs Geddy, we are comparing the thin layer above node.js (connect<->geddy) and its implication on the framework.

Comment: I've never used Geddy, but that presentation feels like a sales pitch.  ("You should use our framework!")  Glancing over the site, it looks like Geddy makes a lot of assumptions about how you want to build your app (like Rails), which may or may not be a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geddy is not better than Connect / Express, the big thing that differs is the structure of it. Like @josh3736 said in his comment, "Geddy makes a lot of assumptions about how you want to build your app (like Rails), which may or may not be a good thing".

The author of Geddy didn't like to see different structures for each project he saw built with Express and how the middleware feature was implemented, so he decided to make Geddy and enforce a structure.

For more details, listen to this episode of NodeUp: http://nodeup.com/seventeen

Comment: I'm the author of those slides, and yes, you pretty much hit the nail on the head here. Connect/Express is great if you want a very minimal set of features to help you build an app on node. Geddy takes things a little further, giving you a structure and some best practices to help you get your app (and your team) up and running quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is basically correct, but the real answer is that Geddy pre-dates Connect. Node's baked-in HTTP support is such that there would not have been any real value in rewriting it to use Connect.